# Video performance on ACER Aspire One on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Lubuntu)

Tags: video, performance, acer, aspire

I'm using an ACER Aspire One with ATOM processor and 2GB RAM running Lubuntu 20.04 Focal.

I believe I should be able to play a simple video file in VLC but it is basically playing back with sound and the frame changes about once every five seconds.  Is there a fix for this - I'm sure the hardware is capable of playing video (no other apps are running).  Is this an issue with Ubuntu - would I be better off with Mint (i.e. is this a driver compatibility/distribution issue)...  Many thanks,

Simon

Comment: try totem (videos)